# How to search through csv files in a folder for a string through excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am using excel vba to find a record in csv files which matches given string
I need help in searching through all csv files in a folder for a particular string and get the file name which contains the search string and from within the file the row itself. The string will always appear in column B of the CSV. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have any code you should post it.  If you haven't yet tried anything, try using `Dir(pathToYourFolder & "*.csv")` to loop through and open each file in the source folder.  Plenty of examples of this here on SO alone.

Answer (score 5):

It might be easier to start a Command Prompt and navigate to your folder containing the CSV files. Then you can do this:

```
FINDSTR /N /I "something" *.CSV
```

where "something" is whatever you are looking for.

Comment: How can i get this into VBA?

Comment: My point was that this probably easier than loading a load of files in Excel by clicking around all over the place.

Comment: seriously saved my time, ive been trying to bang head with powershell

Answer (score 0):

This returns the first file it finds the match, found here http://www.ggkf.com/excel/vba-macro-to-search-a-folder-for-keyword

```
Sub loopThroughFiles()
Dim file As String
file = FindFiles("putyourpathname eg.c:\reports", "search string")
If (file <> "") Then MsgBox file
End Sub
Function FindFiles(ByVal path As String, ByVal target As String) As String
' Run The Shell Command And Get Output
Dim files As String
files = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Exec("FINDSTR /M """ & target & """ """ & path &     "\*.*""").StdOut.ReadAll
FindFiles = ""
If (files <> "") Then
    Dim idx As Integer
    idx = InStr(files, vbCrLf)
    FindFiles = Left(files, idx - 1)
End If
End Function
```